# How to push JSON records into an empty array as individual elements [Angular]

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, jsonplaceholder

I've recently started working on Angular. I'm creating a filter for my Angular application. The scenario is, I've 100(say) users and their personal details in JSON format. I'm using `JSONPlaceholder`, the fake rest API, for this. I'm using `fetch()` method to get all the those user records and all those records have to sit in my local array `usres=[];`. I want this so that later I can display these users on cards and also i would like to apply filter based on name, location, skills, etc. My problem is that I'm not able to `push` values into my `users` array. I tried taking help from:

1. [JSON arrays: w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_json_arrays.asp)
2. [How to convert JSON object to JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528385/how-to-convert-json-object-to-javascript-array)
3. [How to push JSON object in to array using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361864/how-to-push-json-object-in-to-array-using-javascript)

[Here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users) is that entire JSON that I'm talking about.

I'll take care of filtering myself, please help me populate my `users=[];` array. From there I can take charge.

Here is the code.

**card.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  text='';

  users=[];

  filteredUsers=[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => this.users.push(json))
  }

  SearchFunction(text) {
    this.filteredUsers=(this.users.filter(e => {
      return e.name.toLocaleLowerCase() === text.toLocaleLowerCase ||
      e.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }));
    console.log(this.filteredUsers);
  }
}
```

But I think this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrn5xb) will save everyone's time and efforts. Please correct me.

Comment: Please post relevant code (and possibly sample data) here, instead of off-site. Questions should be self-contained and shouldn't require visiting other sites to be answerable.

Comment: Done. I've pasted the relevant code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are pushing an array into array. You should `push`individual elements and `concat` arrays.

It should be either:

```
this.users = json;
```

Or:

```
this.users.concat(json);
```

Or:

```
this.users.push(...json); // Destructure the array first
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Also, should probably use Angular HttpClient for fetching data.

Comment: yes yes, Later I'll use `HttpClient` only. Here I used fake rest api to quickly recreate the problem. :-)

Comment: `this.users = json;` Not working :-( let's try your other solutions.

Comment: It does work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snwvxn?file=src/app/card/card.component.ts

Comment: Yes. It is working. Some stupid mistakes from my side. Sorry.
Can you please explain the solution little bit more.

Comment: I mean, that's just how push and concat work. Read these two links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: And this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: but I still wonder, why my `this.users.push(json)` was not working?

Comment: Because that pushes an array into array. You are creating an array of which the first and only element is another array.

Answer (score 1):

The get requests is returning an array. So you are pushing an array into another array.
Either you can set your users list equals to your json result or u can push each element into the array: "this.users.push(...json)"