# Vuex state.array.push adds objects inside of array row

Tags: arrays, push, vuex, mutation

I develop filter functionality and after pushing array Vuex pushes all objects of array inside one array row.

```
pushFiltered (state, payload) {  
    state.filtered.push(payload)
},
```

This is result on vue dev tools:

```
filtered:Array[3]
0:Object
1:Object
2:Array[2]
  >0:Object
  >1:Object
```

How to extract and push correctly? Also spread operator, concat too not helps.

**UPDATE:**
I found solution. If there is a single object and you want to push whole object into an array then no need to iterate the object. [from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361864/how-to-push-json-object-in-to-array-using-javascript/43362428)

This is my solution:

```
pushFiltered (state, payload) {
        payload.forEach(function(row) {
          state.filtered.push(row)
        });
    }
```

It works but i don't know is good practice or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I guess the first time filtered is not an array, I mean the initial state in the store.

So if you are passing and array of objects and want to push them, you can do it this way:

The initial state of filtered:

```
...
filtered: [],
...
```

The mutation:

```
mergeFiltered (state, payload) {
    state.filtered = [...state.filtered, ...payload]
}
```

That way you are doing a merge between the current values in the filtered array and the incoming payload.